# Eclipse JUnit Arquillian without Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, jboss-arquillian

In my project i have a user library that contains all the necessary libs for running the arquillian junit test and it works perfectly within the IDE.
The problem now is, that the Test classes would be packaged with my main application, causing a ClassNotFoundException, because the arquillian libs are not available.
Can i exclude my test classes somehow from the packaging or do I have to move my tests to a different project that is not part of my main application?

Comment: Just found a working solution, http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t83880.rhtml#92059392